# Is a written contract required/recommended for vacation housing swaps?

Tags: budget, accommodation

Vacation [housing swaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_swapping) are popular. I'm thinking about doing it for my place. Is it common practice to have a written contract between the swappers? Or is it something that is on-your-honor?

Comment: Does anyone have examples?

Comment: Are your prospective swappers citizens of the same country as you?  If not, a contract might be quite difficult to enforce.

Comment: I have done house swapping several times with my family, and we never made any sort of contract. We always used one of the house swap platforms to find the people and usually quite a lot of contact would happen before the actual travel, so that you usually get quite a good idea of the people. For us the mutual trust was always part of the deal and it was an unspoken rule that if you break something you replace it. We never had any sort of problems and met a lot of very welcoming people. But of course, that can be a bit risky.

Answer (score 1):

Good thinking - you've never met these people, and they may have all the good feedback in the world, but you want security and the peace of mind that your place is covered.

There are some sample contracts online you could copy - such as [this](http://www.commuterswap.net/home_swap_agreementh.pdf).

If you're feeling uncertain about asking them for it or how to go about arranging it, HomeExchange (a popular website for house swapping) has [a nice article on how to negotiate a house swap contract](http://support.homeexchange.com/customer/portal/articles/997403-exchange-agreements).